# Android/XML: Make TextView at central of XML when RecyclerView is empty

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Currently, I build an app that uses RecyclerView. The RecyclerView may shows "List is Empty" when there's no data at the list. But, what happens is, the text is absolutely at the center, but not at the center of the XML.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/haha"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyHistoryList">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".80"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="Suggestion"
            android:textAllCaps="true"


   android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="@font/anaheim" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textAllCaps="true"

   android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="@font/anaheim" />
    </TableRow>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recylcerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:text="List is Empty"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Java Code.

```
if(array.length() == 0){
                            //display empty with your code.
                            emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }else {
                            emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject userJson = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                userList.add(new User(
                                        userJson.getInt("id"),
                                        userJson.getString("name").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("badgeid").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("position").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("department").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("factory").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("reviewer").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("title").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("year").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("month").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("suggestionwill").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("present").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("details").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("benefit").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("photo").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("status").replace("null", ""),
                                        userJson.getString("comment").replace("null", "")
                                ));
```

Below is my current XML

https://scontent.fkul8-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/60515690_10216139628056609_7099924834024423424_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&_nc_eui2=AeHvv0bzaCNYPgIufVyqiMZGqXAQPaArqTPCB4Ix5QXrob9n9jb61O1bt03p-heNH0axIeIO8cOXmEyDzgRZJxNGdYtE_KX0CwckEJnIT_7piA&_nc_ht=scontent.fkul8-1.fna&oh=f6ed096592ceefcb151c71acf9393b63&oe=5D6BF3CC

How I want make text "List is Empty" is at the center of XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is your updated layout file. please use it to get your problem's solution.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/haha"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MyHistoryList">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".80"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="Suggestion"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:fontFamily="@font/anaheim" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".20"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="Status"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:fontFamily="@font/anaheim" />
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recylcerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="List is Empty"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you have to handle the code like when you have not got the data in your recyclerView just gone the recyclerview and make visible textView which contains "List Is Empty".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple handles a boolean,
if there is information is true if not false
if the boolean is true, make the recycler visible and hide the textview with the attribute visibility (gone/visible) , and if it is false, you have the opposite,
In case the doubts in your view you must declare the textview and recycler which you will be visible depending on the case.

Answer (score 0):

Set LinearLayout gravity to center

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/haha"
     android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MyHistoryList">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```